# Put classes files in WEB-INF

Tags: java, class, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have directory with classes files.
I want to put them in the WEB-INF/classes directory, I don't have the source Java files, just the classes.

When I start tomcat I got error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`
because there is listener in the web.xml that call some class that exists in my classes directory.

How can I do that?

I tried to insert the classes files to JAR and add it to the project library,
but I am still getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I tried to put the directory with the classes in the `src` directory but same, I got error that the class not found.

Comment: More information about the Exception is needed. It sounds likely that the call for your classes is not happening from your web app classloader but from a higher-level classloader that won't have access to it, or perhaps from a classloader in another sibling web app. Can you post more information like log msgs with the stacktrace? Do you know what class is throwing the excepting? Cheers!

Comment: *"I tried to insert the classes files to JAR"* Were they added to the **correct path** in the JAR file, using the package names as paths for the classes? BTW: Always copy/paste *entire* error and exception output!

Comment: Tnx i solved the problem by delete work directory in the tomcat